# AngularJS - Create dynamic properties to an object/model from json

Tags: json, angularjs, object

OK, we all know this works:

```
vm.myObject = { 
             required : "This field requires data",
             .....
           }
```

But how can I create that same object dynamically when the property 'keys' and 'values' come from a json file, eg:

json:

```
     [
       { "key" :"required", "value": "This field requires data"},
         .....
     ]
```

---

service:

```
  var myObject = {}
  DynamicObjSvc.get()
        .success(function(data){
            data.forEach(function(item){
               // pass each key as an object property
               // and pass its respective value
                ?????????
            })
        .....
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Kavemen was mostly correct, this turned out to be the solution:

```
    var myObject = {};
    DynamicObjSvc.all()
        .success(function(data){
           angular.forEach(data, function(msg) {
               myObject[msg.key] = msg.value; <-- his answer was incorrect here
            });
            $fgConfigProviderRef.validation.message(myObject);
        })
        .error(function(err){
            console.log(err.message);
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) and the bracket notation for setting (and getting) object properties in Javascript

```
var myObject = {}
DynamicObjSvc.get().success(
    function(data) {
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) { 
            myObject[key] = value;
        });
    }
);
```

See also [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) from MDN

**EDIT**

I see now that your `data` is really an array of objects, not just a single object, so yes, the code above could lead you astray.

In any case, the method of setting an object's properties dynamically using the bracket notation is sound; the loop could be reworked to handle your `data` array as such:

```
//we have an array of objects now
var myObjects = [];
DynamicObjSvc.get().success(
    function(data) {
        //for each object in the data array
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //create and populate a new object for the ith data element
            var newObject = {};
            angular.forEach(data[i], function(value, key) { 
                newObject[key] = value;
            });
            //and add it to the overall collection
            myObjects.push(newObject);
        }
    }
);
```